# modifying query resultset to include all dates in a range

Tags: oracle, groovy

I have a query which I run on a table `TXN_DEC(id, resourceid, usersid, date, eventdesc)` which return distinct count of users for a given date-range and resourceid, group by date and eventdesc (each resource can have 4 to 5 eventdesc)

if there is no value of distinct users count on a date in the range, for an eventdesc, then it skips that date row in the resultset.

I need to have all date rows in my resultset or collection such that if there is no value of count for a date,eventdesc combination, then its value is set to 0 but that date still exists in the collection..

How do I go about getting such a collection

I know getting the final dataset entirely from the query result would be too complicated,
but I can use collections in groovy to modify and populate my map/list to get the data in the required format

something similar to following: if

> input date range = 5th Feb to 3 March 2011

```
      DataMap = [dateval: '02/05/2011' eventdesc: 'Read' dist_ucnt: 23,
                 dateval: '02/06/2011' eventdesc: 'Read' dist_ucnt: 23,
                 dateval: '02/07/2011' eventdesc: 'Read' dist_ucnt: 0,  -> this row was not present in query resultset, but row exists in the map with value 0
                 ....and so on till 3 march 2011 and then whole range repeated for each eventdesc
                     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all dates (including those with no entries in your TXN_DEC table) for a given range, you could use Oracle to generate your date range and then use an outer join to your existing query.  Then you would just need to fill in null values.  Something like:

```
select 
    d.dateInRange as dateval,
    'Read' as eventdesc,
    nvl(td.dist_ucnt, 0) as dist_ucnt
from (
    select 
        to_date('02-FEB-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') + rownum - 1 as dateInRange
    from all_objects
    where rownum <= to_date('03-MAR-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') - to_date('02-FEB-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') + 1
) d
left join (
    select 
        date,
        count(distinct usersid) as dist_ucnt
    from
        txn_dec
    where eventDesc = 'Read'
    group by date 
) td on td.date = d.dateInRange
```

That's my purely Oracle solution since I'm not a Groovy guy (well, actually, I am a pretty groovy guy...)

EDIT:  Here's the same version wrapped in a stored procedure.  It should be easy to call if you know the API....

```
create or replace procedure getDateRange (
    p_begin_date IN DATE, 
    p_end_date IN DATE, 
    p_event IN txn_dec.eventDesc%TYPE,
    p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_recordset FOR
    select 
        d.dateInRange as dateval,
        p_event as eventdesc,
        nvl(td.dist_ucnt, 0) as dist_ucnt
    from (
        select 
            p_begin_date + rownum - 1 as dateInRange
        from all_objects
        where rownum <= p_end_date - p_begin_date + 1
    ) d
    left join (
        select 
            date,
            count(distinct usersid) as dist_ucnt
        from
            txn_dec
        where eventDesc = p_event
        group by date 
    ) td on td.date = d.dateInRange;
END getDateRange;
```

Comment: this looks good, do you by any chance know how to use hibernate (like HQL) for this. Even createCriteria api is fine...?

Comment: ok.. I can try converting above solution, but only issue is that the event desc can be anything from (Read, Write, Save.. etc) its not fixed value 'Read' hence I need to also group by eventdesc. Thanks for the help..

Comment: Check out my edit.  I wrapped it in a stored procedure.  I would imagine Hibernate has an API for talking to Oracle stored procedures.

Comment: Really Appreciate the Solution, the problem is we cannot use stored procedures in our implementation since it would be a database management responsibility addition. I modified the query and it ran on oracle giving the required result, I have to now just convert it to HQL, as I am not sure about the createCriteria api in Hibernate..